# how to disable Pull-Up-Refresh in PullToRefreshScrollView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I use PullToRefreshScrollView in https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh.

It includes PullDownToRefresh and PullUpToRefresh,but I don't need the PullUpToRefresh since I get a Bottom MenuDrawer;

I guess there might be a parameter to store the refresh action in the source  code.Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: That project was deprecated years ago. Please use `SwipeRefreshLayout` from Android support v4. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the README file of the project, there is this link: https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh#pull-up-to-refresh

If you want to disable the PullUpToRefresh behavior, you can call `yourView.setMode(Mode.PULL_FROM_START);`

Hope this helps.

Comment: So in my case, I should call: mPullToRefreshSrollView.setMode(Mode.PULL_FROM_START),is that right?